# Building a MySQL database that can take an infinite number of fields

Tags: sql, dynamic-columns

I am building a MySQL-driven website that will analyze customer surveys distributed by a variety of clients. Generally, these surveys are structured fairly consistently, and most of our clients' data can be reduced to the same normalized database structure.

However, every client inevitably ends up including highly specific demographic questions for their customers that are irrelevant to every other one of our clients. For instance, although all of our clients will ask about customer satisfaction, only our auto clients will ask whether the customers know how to drive manual transmissions.

Up to now, I have been adding columns to a `respondents` table for all general demographic information, with a lot of `default null`'s mixed in. However, as we add more clients, it's clear that this will end up with a massive number of columns which are almost always null.

Is there a way to do this consistently? I would rather keep as much of the standardized data as possible in the `respondents` table since our import script is already written for that table. One thought of mine is to build a `respondent_supplemental_demographic_info` table that has the columns response_id, demographic_field, demographic_value (so the manual transmissions example might become: 'ID999', 'can_drive_manual_indicator', true). This could hold an infinite number of demographic_fields, but would be incredible painful to work with from both a processing and programming perspective. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution to this problem is called entity-attribute-value (EAV).  This "unpivots" columns so they are rows in a table and then you tie them together into a single view.

EAV structures are a bit tricky to learn how to deal with.  They require many more joins or aggregations to get a single view out.  Also, the types of the values becomes challenging.  Generally there is one value column, so everything is stored as a string.  You can, of course, have a type column with different types.

They also take up more space, because the entity id is repeated on each row (I think that is the `response_id` in your case).

Although not idea in all situations, they are appropriate in a situation such as you describe.  You are adding attributes indefinitely.  You will quickly run over the maximum number of columns allowed in a single table (typically between 1,000 and 4,000 depending on the database).  You can also keep track of each value in each column separately -- if they are added at different times, for instance, you can keep a time stamp on when they go in.

Another alternative is to maintain a separate table for each client, and then use some other process to combine the data into a common data structure.

Comment: So if I take an EAV approach, will I be able to build views that convert these row-value combinations back into columns using SQL? Or is this something complicated enough that it would need to be done php-side? What I would probably do if I took this approach is: keep the core table with the standardized data and then build a single EAV table as well. Then, if this can be handled in SQL, I'd build one view per client that would have all the core data and would generate the supplemental demographic columns from the EAV table, assuming these would be fairly consistent for each client

Comment: i.e. our automotive customer would keep his "satisfaction" analysis in the `respondents` table, his `can_drive_manual_indicator` in an EAV table, and then that client would have his own view for all surveys which would be the `respondents` table with the client-specific demographic fields appended, like `can_drive_manual_indicator`. Is that view possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Do not fall for a table with key-value pairs (field id, field value) as that is inefficient.

In your case I would create a table per customer. And metadata tables (in a separate DB) describing these tables. With these metadata you can generate SQL etcetera. That is definitely superior too having many null columns. Or copied, adapted scripts. It requires a bit of programming, where an application uses the metadata to generate SQL, collect the data (without customer specific semantic knowledge) and generate reports.